# Collapsing margin on Flexbox grid in Edge and Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox, microsoft-edge

I have created a grid layout using flexbox and when the items appear on multiple rows the margins between them collapse. This only happens on Microsoft Edge and Firefox.

Here is my code on Codepen: https://codepen.io/stephenhlane/pen/BdvxzP

Any ideas how to fix this?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-1">
    <h2>Item one</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-2">
    <h2>Item two</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-3">
    <h2>Item three</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-4">
    <h2>Item four</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-5">
    <h2>Item five</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-6">
    <h2>Item six</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  padding: 1.5%;
  background-color: #333;
}

.container {
  max-width: 964px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -moz-box-flex-flow:  row wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow:  row wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow:  row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 30.333%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4286f4;
  padding: 0 20px 40px;
  margin: 1.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Margin using percent doesn't work cross browsers on flex items, so if your margin's is more related to the viewport, use viewport units (`vh` or `vw`), else you can combine `px` with CSS `calc()` (i.e. `width: calc(33.333% - 20px)`) to match an equal *gutter* between the items.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ayXmrW)

```css
body {
  padding: 1.5%;
  background-color: #333;
}

.container {
  //background-color: black;
  max-width: 964px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -moz-box-flex-flow:  row wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow:  row wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow:  row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 97%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4286f4;
  padding: 0 20px 40px;
  margin: 1.5vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:420px){
  .item {
    width: 47%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px){
  .item {
    width: 30.333%;
  }
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-1">
    <h2>Item one</h2>
    <p>Pellentesque convallis turpis nec enim consequat, vitae pellentesque purus tempus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis blandit elit vel lacus gravida, nec imperdiet ligula ornare.</p>
    <a href="#">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-2">
    <h2>Item two</h2>
    <p>Pellentesque convallis turpis nec enim consequat, vitae pellentesque purus tempus.</p>
    <a href="#">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-3">
    <h2>Item three</h2>
    <p>Pellentesque convallis turpis nec enim consequat, vitae pellentesque purus tempus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.</p>
    <a href="#">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-4">
    <h2>Item four</h2>
    <p>Pellentesque convallis turpis nec enim consequat.</p>
    <a href="#">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-5">
    <h2>Item five</h2>
    <p>Pellentesque convallis turpis nec enim consequat.</p>
    <a href="#">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-6">
    <h2>Item six</h2>
    <p>Pellentesque convallis turpis nec enim consequat.</p>
    <a href="#">Read more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```